# Does Visual Studio 2015 Community edition support Roslyn?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, roslyn

Can I use Roslyn and all its tooling in Visual Studio 2015 Community edition?

I am about to download the community edition and it's a big decision for me given that I have a single piece of hardware, my laptop, which I use for everything, and the only reason I am going to download 2015 is because I want to practice coding Roslyn, which is not available in the VS 2013 or earlier expression editions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Roslyn" is just the compiler platform in Visual Studio 2015. So yes, the Community edition has Roslyn.

We've been referring to it by its code name for so long that it's not really clear, but "Roslyn" is simply a rewrite of the C# and VB .NET compilers in managed code. On top of the compiler platform, you can write extensions to interact with code and the IDE as it's parsed in the form of quickfixes and refactorings.

The Visual Studio Community editions are nearly functionally identical to Visual Studio Professional, albeit under different license terms. This includes extension support.

The Roslyn [GitHub page](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn) has awesome documentation to help you get your head wrapped around it.

Comment: Thank you. Some of the tooling (esp. the IDE features) were implemented as plug-ins/Visual Studio add-ins and hence were not available in Expression editions because expression editions did not support add-ins. Therefore, I wanted to confirm with someone who is using the community edition if they are able to use all the tooling.

Comment: Also, if I wanted to write a program to, say, do semantic analysis or another piece of code, that program would be implemented as a Visual Studio add-in, right? So, I would need the full-blown Visual Studio thing, which isn't possible in the earlier (2013 and earlier) express editions.

Comment: Express editions were pared down. Community is identical to Professional, except the license terms are different.

Comment: Thank you. Just what I needed to know. I feared express was just a marketing term, which has now become community. Glad community is almost professional.

Comment: I'd seen the edition comparison chart but couldn't tell just by looking at it. Thanks for the confirmation.

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2: If you just want to use the Roslyn APIs to analyze code, you don't need a VS addin at all; you can write a console app that reads a text file and parses it into a syntax tree.  You don't need any VS support for that at all (you can even do it in 2013 Express); just add the Roslyn NuGet packages.